# Android wifi p2p unsupported (wifidirect)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, p2p, wifi-direct

i'm using the protocol for making p2p connection using wifi in android (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)

I have a problem calling the **discoverPeers()** function :

ActionListener.onFailure(int reason)  is called (its an interface to trigger some events) and i receive reason=1, which means 'P2P_UNSUPPORTED'.
I added all the permissions required and the (use... wifidirect) tag.

i'm using a virtual device and the latest android sdk(4.0.3),
i have an internet connection on this device.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: post your code with manifast permission

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't run the demo in the emulator because it doesn't support real Wifi.
You should launch the demo on a real device like the Galaxy Nexus which supports ICS and Wifi-Direct.

Comment: ok , i'll try (if i have enough money to buy it). But i hope there is a way to make it work on AVDs

Answer (score 0):

*facepalm* Yea...I was running on an emulator instead of the real deal...works fine if you use a device that ACTUALLY has Wifi...ha!